# Samsung Galaxy S4 not getting software updates of 4.3 or 4.4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, android-versions

I have a galaxy s4 device running on 4.2.2. I am not getting any updates for the same. When I do check for updates it says "You already have the latest version". I know 4.3 has officially released for galaxy s4.

I don't want to root my phone and update it. Since it is officially released why i am not getting the updates ?

Please suggest any solution so that i can get my phone on latest OS version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes OTA (over the air) upgrades are very late to turn up.  Also, your carrier can delay things, which is nice of them.  You should try installing Samsung's Kies software and upgrade that way.

Comment: It also depends on country rite?